# Disply the list of users with total posts

Tags: python, django

How can I display the list of users with the count of total number of posts made by them in a separate HTML page ?

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author       =  models.ForeignKey(User.request, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    title        =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text         =  models.TextField()
    slug         =  models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, default=uuid.uuid1)
    created_date =  models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    likes        =  models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='post_likes', blank = True)

    def get_like_url(self):
       return reverse("posts:like-toggle", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def get_api_like_url(self):
       return reverse("posts:like-api-toggle", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse("post_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
       return self.title

    def count_posts_of(user):
       return Post.objects.filter(author=user).count()
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details? What you've tried, what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am new to django. I am trying to display a list of users with the total count of posts they have made and have written a function called count_posts_of for that but not sure if its correct. And how shall i display it on a separate html page ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to learn MVC architecture(MVT in django).

As a beginner first create a sample project to understand this - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/

Learn how `models.py` are written - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/
and how to write`views.py` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/
Then connect them in `urls.py` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution at the moment, but it could be done differently.

First, add count_posts_of method to your User model whatever it is.
For instance I myself created a user model and add this method to it as following:

models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

@property
def count_posts_of(self):
    return self.post_set.all().count()
```

now in the view pass all the users as context:

views.py

```
def user_post(request):
context = {'users': User.objects.all()}
return render(request, 'future/user_post_view.html', context)
```

and finally in the template show the user and their posts' count:

user_post_view.html

```
{% for user in users %}
{{ user.name }} :
{{ user.count_posts_of }},
{% endfor %}
```